# Поле UUID в Базе Данных

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Приветствую!
Возникла проблема в том чтобы сделать поле в таблицы, которое будет генерировать уникальное значение. Нужно оно для создания уникального значения брони. Возможно ли это сделать на уровне Базы или триггером, а не кодом. Наткнулся на команду `uuid`, обычным `SELECT`-ом работает но как сделать это для `INSERT`-а в Базу?

Comment: а что так не работает? insert into users values(uuid(), 'data');

Comment: UUID, UUID_SHORT  являются небезопасными для statement based replication. А что если в триггере на создание использовать значение уникального ключа таблицы плюс какая строка:  '1001_bron' ?,

Comment: А что означает 'data'? Я хотел сделать где то 8-10 символом и 3 буквы или вообще без букв(но без букв думаю небезопасно)
А как еще можно реализовать если не uuid?

Comment: _без букв думаю небезопасно_ Поясните, о какой (или каких) именно безопасности идёт речь. Думаю, это момент существенный, и его лучше внести в сам вопрос.Заодно поясните, чем не устраивает. например, вульгарный SERIAL.

Comment: Я лично не вижу смысла хранить в БД большие строки ради уникальных значений. Я бы сделал обычный автоинкрементный ID, а если на клиенте надо сгенерить какую нибудь ссылку, что бы была не заметена закономерность в генерации - добавить какую нибудь фиксированную строку, зашифровать любым обратимым алгоритмом (DES, AES и т.п.) и применить к этому base64/85/итп кодировку что бы получить буквы или вообще в шестнадцеричке. при получении этого обратно расшифровываете - получаете ID

Comment: Это нужно для двухфакторной оплаты банка, автоинкремент думаю будет не совсем удобен, так как данная запись будет дергаться CallBack-ом.Возможен такой вариант только упростить в количестве символов: id_text varchar(36) generated always as
 (insert(
    insert(
      insert(
        insert(hex(id_bin),9,0,'-'),
        14,0,'-'),
      19,0,'-'),
    24,0,'-')
 ) virtual,
name varchar(200));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почитал, посмотрел решил все же через код в `INSERT`-е сделать: `INSERT INTO`tbooking`(`bookingcode`) VALUES (UUID())`